# WinServer 2008 R2 SP1, IIS 7.5 upgrade to TLS 1.2 or 1.3

Tags: iis-7.5, tls1.2, windows-server-2008-r2

When browse my website on Firefox and look console I see this warning

> This site uses a deprecated version of TLS that will be disabled in March 2020. Please upgrade to TLS 1.2 or 1.3

I've followed this guidelines to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows from

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi

I download and manual install `kb3140245` then use `Easyfix` for update Registry and restart server

But I still see warning above and don't know how to resolve it

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is end of life. You have to upgrade to a newer Windows release.

Comment: yes, 2008 is end of life. but to resolve the issue you could try to use the IIS crypto and enable tls 1.1 and 1.2. you could download that extension from this [link](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thank for your comment but It's server environment so I cannot use tool from non official source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution from here: https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/

1. Backup your registry
2. Open registry on your server by running `regedit` in run window and navigate to below location

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols

3. Add the `TLS 1.1` and `TLS 1.2` keys under `Protocols`. It will looks like directories
4. Now create two keys `Client` and `Server` under both `TLS 1.1` and `TLS 1.2` keys
5. Create the `DWORD` Values under `Server` and `Client` key of `TLS 1.1` as following

   ```
    DisabledByDefault [Value = 0]
    Enabled [Value = 0]
   ```
6. Create the `DWORD` Values under `Server` and `Client` key of `TLS 1.2` as following

   ```
    DisabledByDefault [Value = 0]
    Enabled [Value = 1]
   ```

   [image]
7. Restart server and warning is gone